# Math.Round fail on AwayFromZero mode

Tags: c#, asp.net

Could someone tell me what is going wrong with following piece of code?
It returns 0.14 instead of 0.15

```
Math.Round(0.145, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

Comment: The too short version: `0.145` is not exactly equal to `145.0 / 1000.0`. It's actually slightly less. This has been asked before a lot.

Comment: Ok any idea about having a saver Round AwayFromZero? Maybe converting it to decimal?

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: If this is important, you should probably use `decimal` instead of `double`.

Comment: @user1392203 `decimal` would be one way, if the values you're dealing with are exactly representable in that type. (That means using `0.145m`.) Of course, `decimal` also has rounding issues that may or may not become a problem for you. One third represented in `decimal` is probably less accurate than one third represented in `double`.

Answer (score 0):

If the decimals are important use decimal datatype.

There are books up and down on this subject and it's important to read up on this.
But the short version is this.

```
var a = Math.Round(0.145, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
//a == 0.14
var b = Math.Round(0.145m, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
//b == 0.15
```

So you just need to declare your variable as decimal.